# SOQL Query With Running Tally or Running Totals

Tags: soql, rest-api, api, dynamic-soql

I have a Payments object with dates and corresponding payments. We can query the data via SOQL in our API and the data looks like this:

```
SELECT Date, Amount FROM Payments WHERE CreatedDate>2019-01-01 AND Account=0011K00009994H5
~
Date        | Amount
------------+--------
2019-01-01  |  30.00
2019-01-02  |  20.00
2019-01-03  |  30.00
2019-01-04  |  20.00
2019-01-05  |  30.00
2019-01-06  |  20.00
```

We would like to run a single SQL query shows a running total of payments by date looks like this:

```
Date        | Amount | Total
------------+--------+--------
2019-01-01  |  30.00 |  30.00
2019-01-02  |  20.00 |  50.00
2019-01-03  |  30.00 |  80.00
2019-01-04  |  20.00 | 100.00
2019-01-05  |  30.00 | 130.00
2019-01-06  |  20.00 | 150.00
```

I know how to do this in SQL Server or MYSQL but is this possible using SOQL in one query?

PS: We are currently doing this manually using multiple queries and we are constantly running out of API requests.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, SOQL does not have functionality like this. You can find the overall SUM() of a field but not in a running total.

Here is a link to the available SOQL Aggregate Functions: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm

I believe to achieve this in Salesforce, you'd need to combine this with Apex and hold the running total in a variable you can then print to Visualforce Page or Aura/Lightning Component.

Comment: Thanks - I'd like to keep the question open for a while before accepting this answer. I'm hoping someone can add a workaround that can be called via the SOQL API endpoint.